# Click on button of particular cell of webtable by verifying values of two different columns of same table using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Below is my code to click on button of specific column by verifying the values of two columns of that same row:

```
    for (int rowCntr = 0; rowCntr < row1.size(); rowCntr++)
    {
        if(row1.get(rowCntr).getAttribute("value").contains(loanName))
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            List<WebElement> col1 = row1.get(rowCntr).findElements(By.tagName("td"));
            int colCntr = col1.size();

            for (int j = 0; j < colCntr; j++)
            {

                if(col1.get(j).getText().contains("Submitted"))
                {
                    icon_Review.click();
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: Hello could you please add a bit more information about what the actual error is you are getting and what the actual question is?

Comment: For get webtable value, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52393052/how-to-read-cell-values-in-a-table-using-selenium-webdriver/52397617#52397617) maybe will help you

Answer (score 0):

Does row has attribute , called value ?
if yes and click is failing , you can use Javascript executor or action class for click.